# Trying to extract data and write to another spreadsheet comes up empty

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The output file is created but only the first cell is written and nothing else. I tested it with system print and all the data that I want shows up in console but is not written to the worksheet.

```
public class excel_read_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/h.M/Desktop/20151007-110016_outgoing.xls")); //input
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);           

        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/h.M/Desktop/workbook.xls");  //output

        int rowcounter = 0;
        for (int rowNum = 150; rowNum < 180; rowNum++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum); 
            if (r == null) {
                continue;
            }
            int lastColumn=6;
            for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                if (c == null){
                }           
                else if (c.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {                
                    Row row = sheet1.createRow((short)rowcounter);
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cn);
                    row.createCell(cn).setCellValue(c.getStringCellValue());

                    System.out.println("The cell was a string \" " + c.getStringCellValue()+" \" ");

                } else if (c.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    Row row = sheet1.createRow((short)rowcounter);
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cn);
                    row.createCell(cn).setCellValue(c.getNumericCellValue());

                    System.out.println("The cell was a number " + c.getNumericCellValue());
                }
            }
            rowcounter++;           
        } 
                    wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you mean? I already have that at the bottom above file.close()

Comment: are you sure it's not in the file?  print out the row/col values as well and see if they are not out of whack.

Comment: They look fine to me and here are the results:
http://pastebin.com/nwhag1Zg

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking to see if the rows in the second workbook are there, and only creating if not? Seems to me that you'll be zapping everything by creating a new row for each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the new row before you loop, then use it once per loop.

```
                Row row = sheet1.createRow((short)rowcounter);
                int lastColumn=6;
                for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
                    Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                    if (c == null){
                    }           
                    else if (c.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cn);
                        cell.setCellValue(c.getStringCellValue());
```